# OpenCV - Why this build error?

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt

I have typed the following program from `Learning OpenCV` book:

```
#include "highgui.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  IplImage *img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
  cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cvShowImage("Example1", img);
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage(&img);
  cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
}
```

When I try to build it using `Eclipse CDT`, I get the following (Any ideas?):

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project OpenCV ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -IC:\OpenCV2.0\include\opencv -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\opencv.o ..\src\opencv.cpp
In file included from C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2243,
                 from C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:2123,
                 from C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/highgui.h:47,
                 from ..\src\opencv.cpp:1:
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp: In member function `void cv::Ptr<_Tp>::addref()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:1442: error: there are no arguments to `__exchange_and_add' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of `__exchange_and_add' must be available
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:1442: error: (if you use `-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp: In member function `void cv::Ptr<_Tp>::release()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:1446: error: there are no arguments to `__exchange_and_add' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of `__exchange_and_add' must be available
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp: In member function `cv::Ptr<_Tp>& cv::Ptr<_Tp>::operator=(const cv::Ptr<_Tp>&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:1473: error: there are no arguments to `__exchange_and_add' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of `__exchange_and_add' must be available
In file included from C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2244,
                 from C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxcore.h:2123,
                 from C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/highgui.h:47,
                 from ..\src\opencv.cpp:1:
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In copy constructor `cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:102: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:102: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In constructor `cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Range&, const cv::Range&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:174: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:174: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In constructor `cv::Mat::Mat(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Rect&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:189: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:189: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `cv::Mat& cv::Mat::operator=(const cv::Mat&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:239: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:239: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `void cv::Mat::addref()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:342: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:342: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `void cv::Mat::release()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:346: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:346: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In copy constructor `cv::MatND::MatND(const cv::MatND&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3648: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3648: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `cv::MatND& cv::MatND::operator=(const cv::MatND&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3677: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3677: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `void cv::MatND::addref()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3717: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3717: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `void cv::MatND::release()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3722: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:3722: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `cv::SparseMat& cv::SparseMat::operator=(const cv::SparseMat&)':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:4081: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:4081: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `void cv::SparseMat::addref()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:4112: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:4112: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function `void cv::SparseMat::release()':
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:4116: error: `__exchange_and_add' was not declared in this scope
C:/OpenCV2.0/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:4116: warning: unused variable '__exchange_and_add'
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 28061  ms.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly using a newer compiler than the OpenCV designers, so it reports a violation of the rules for templates. It also says that if you use -fpermissive, it will be less strict and do like the older compilers used to.

A quick googling also shows that there is now also an OpenCV 2.1. Perhaps that one works better?

Comment: The current version is `OpenCV 2.2`

Comment: Ok, so my googling **was** a bit quick. :-) I would have tried that version then, if I had the newest compiler.